# Get google Email from API

Tags: .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I have authorized `DriveService` object. Is there any way to get email of authorized user? I am able to get display name, but not the email address.

```
OAuth2Authenticator auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, client => GetAuthorization(client));

DriveService service = new DriveService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            Authenticator = auth
        }
    );

Console.WriteLine(service_.About.Get().Fetch().User.DisplayName);
```

`GetAuthorization` function opens browser and allows user to authorize.

```
private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
{
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[]
    {
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
    });

    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);

    using (LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow(arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state).ToString()))
    {
        if (login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(login.AuthorizationToken, state);
        }
    }

    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your current codes?

Comment: You are using Google Drive to get the user details? You're in wrong direction. User object does not contain email. Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get

Comment: I'm not using google drive to get user details. I'm using google drive for accessing user storage, but I need to know the authorized user email. It looks very reasonable to me. If API alows authorization it should alow to get authorized user details as well.

Comment: Drive API does not provide such information. You have to use other API , as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Add this url to scope:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

It loads name, public profile url, email, gender, photo etc.

and after you are authorized get the information from this Json response:

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json

```
 IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[]
    {
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    });
```

**EDIT**

Add the scope to your AuthorizationState constructor

```
 List<string> scopes = new List<string>();                
 scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
```

Comment: Thanks. No way to get this using API?

Comment: I didn't get it. How you get email here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the scope:
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
2. Use this code:

   ```
   private string FetchUsersEmail()
   {
       var emailRequest = @"https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email?alt=json&access_token=" + GoogleAccessToken;
       string jsonString;
       var request = WebRequest.Create(emailRequest);

       using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
       using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
       using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
       {
           jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
       }

       var json = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
       var currentGoogleEmail = json["data"]["email"].Value<string>();

       return currentGoogleEmail;
   }
   ```

   I use Newtonsoft to parse the json, but you can use any other library.

Answer (score 0):

Use [About.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get)

```
DriveService driveService = ...

var req = driveService.About.Get();
req.Fields = "user(displayName,photoLink, me, emailAddress), storageQuota(limit,usage), maxImportSizes, maxUploadSize";
About ab = await req.ExecuteAsync();
```